# RSA Cryptosystems

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, cryptography

I'm looking for references  or papers about the math behind RSA cryptosystems. All I have found is the description of the RSA algorithm and examples but not a deep explanation on the maths behind it. Can you suggest me any sources, or papers, or something like that? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've added the "reference-request" tag to your question; feel free to roll back my edit if you feel it does not belong.

Comment: @JuanDiegoChavesSanguino: How about the original paper https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf? Also, things like: https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf

Comment: Potentially helpful short-and-sweet:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746294/rsa-encryption-confusion-about-the-moduli/2746339#2746339

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any book on abstract algebra. It relies primarily on a theorem from group theory called Lagrange's theorem. Euler's theorem and Fermat's little theorem are special cases of this.

Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian should be just fine.

Also Algebra by Sepanski does well actually in developing modular arithmetic early in the book and explains the RSA algorithm at an appropriate time. So that would be a good one as well.